# How do I allow users to enter html tags in textbox without runtime errors?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, runtime, encode

I have an input textbox on an asp.net page and when a user inputs any tags like break tags or bold an error occurs. I currently am using the following to encode the input:

```
Server.HtmlEncode(mytextbox.Text)
```

However this only encodes characters when they aren't phrased as an html tag, like if the input is `"<<<>>>>>"` is there a way for me to allow the user to put the tags in without it leading to a runtime error?

Comment: DUPLICATE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673107/how-do-i-allow-html-tags-to-be-submitted-in-a-textbox-in-asp-net

Comment: Is this an internal application, as opposed to public facing?

Answer (score 0):

In you **ASP.NET** page's first line, just disable `ValidateRequest`:

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" ValidateRequest="false" %>`