# Allow html and special character inside text box. A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script. The data might represent an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. If this type of input is appropriate in your application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly allow it

Comment: i think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673107/how-do-i-allow-html-tags-to-be-submitted-in-a-textbox-in-asp-net this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET will not accept HTML in posted data unless you disable the validation for the given controller method.

Something like

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff(InputModel model)
```

Another method is to use  [AllowHtml] on the InputModel property that may contain HTML

```
public class InputModel {
[AllowHtml]
public string HtmlData { get; set; }
public string PlainTextData { get; set; }
```

The last method is the safest, it only allows HTML on one specific property.
The first method allows HTML on all string properties on the InputModel class, including `PlainTextData`

Comment: I'm looking into an issue where I have everything you described above, the [ValidateInput(false)] and also [AllowHtml] on the view model properties and am still getting this error, but only in prod.  Not in any other non prod env.  Any ideas what I could check?

Answer (score 1):

**For MVC Use [ValidateInput(false)] on your controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult AddEditFormDetails(Model model)
{}
```

**For Web Form use validateRequest="false" in your control**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustodyArrangement" validateRequest="false" runat="server" Width="100%" />
```