# Adding <br> tag in textbox asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have an textbox in my page need to add 
 tag in it. when i try to save it, it results an Potentially dangerous Request was detected error.

I have tried Pagevalidate="fasle" and requestvalidationmode in webconfig but still i get the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i allow HTML tags to be submitted in a textbox in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673107/how-do-i-allow-html-tags-to-be-submitted-in-a-textbox-in-asp-net)

Comment: are you using mvc 4?

Comment: @freefaller I had tried the same but not helped in my case.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath no iam using asp.net 4.0

Comment: Can you set ValidateRequest="false" to your page directive

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath i tried it already